# how to recover blog from mysql in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

After I reinstall wordpress, all the blogs are disappeared. But when I look into the database, I can find the blogs are still there in database. How can I extract the blog and put it into wordpress again?

Comment: Sounds like a configuration error more than a "disappearing" thing. It's probably just looking in the wrong database, or the wrong tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, backup the DB immidiatly .

after that - check your `wp-config` for correct values ( `DB name` , `Pass` , `DB user` , `DB address` `DB prefix` .  ( my bet is that your prefix is wrong ..)

Then if nothing wrong there - check your DB for `blog_url` and `home_url` inside `wp_options` for correct values .

In your question - you have said :

> After I reinstall wordpress, all the blogs are disappeared

**A** . What do you mean by `reinstall` - did you

1. just FTP´d the files , or
2. run through the install script ?

if ( 1 == true ) Then you might have overwritten `.htaccess` or `wp-config`

if ( 2 == true ) Then probably is the db prefix . (but can also be more serious )

**B** : since you said `all the blogs` in plural - is that a multisite install ?? that would render things a bit more complicated to pinpoint if the above methods do not work .

**EDIT I** - well -  it seems I was not wrong about the prefix ..

```
Rename table old_prefix_commentmeta to new_prefix_commentmeta;
Rename table old_prefix_comments to new_prefix_comments;
Rename table old_prefix_links to new_prefix_links;
Rename table old_prefix_options to new_prefix_options;
Rename table old_prefix_postmeta to new_prefix_postmeta;
Rename table old_prefix_posts to new_prefix_posts;
Rename table old_prefix_terms to new_prefix_terms;
Rename table old_prefix_term_relationships to new_prefix_term_relationships;
Rename table old_prefix_term_taxonomy to new_prefix_term_taxonomy;
Rename table old_prefix_usermeta to new_prefix_usermeta;
Rename table old_prefix_users to new_prefix_users;
```

After that you need to edit `new_prefix_options` table ( formally `old_prefix_options` ) :

you will need to change `old_prefix_user_roles` to `new_prefix_user_roles`.

Now , apply changes to `new_prefix_usermeta` formally ( `old_prefix_usermeta` )

Change every value under meta_key , that starts with the old_prefix to the new_prefix.
The number or records will be different depending on your previous config, plugins, themes etc ..

some common ones can be :

```
old_prefix_capabilities to new_prefix_capabilities
old_prefix_autosave_draft_ids to new_prefix_autosave_draft_ids
old_prefix_user_level  to new_prefix_user_level
old_prefix_usersettings to new_prefix_usersettings
```

The best way to be sure is run a search with `meta_key like old_prefix_%` in PHPMyadmin.

There are also [plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/change-table-prefix/) for that ( [LINK](http://wordpress.org/plugins/change-table-prefix/) ) , but i am not 100% sure it can help since you actually not have the system installed yet . ( but for future reference )

Anyhow - you still did not say if it is a multisite or not - but basically it is the same ( only in multisite you will have multiple options to change ..

As for "loosing" theme and styles - as long as those are not written in DB wit hsome plugin ( styles ) than just reactivating the theme should do the trick ..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I run the install script, and there are some prefix issue. The original one is yan_, and the new one is wp_. But if I change the prefix to the original one, I lost all theme and style in my blog. Is there anyway to copy the content of my original table to new ones?

Comment: ... I assumed it is the prefix . See my EDIT I